# defining keys in play framework application conf file

Tags: java, database, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to add new keys in application.conf file in play framework 2.1. I have added the following keys:

```
gen.db.host=localhost
gen.db.port=27017
gen.db.name=test
```

When i start my application, it is throwing the following error:

```
Configuration error: Configuration error[application.conf: 46: port has type NUMBER rather than OBJECT]
......
......
......
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: application.conf: 46: port has type NUMBER rather than OBJECT
```

I don't understand this issue. How can i resolve it? Also, is it a good practice to define new keys in application.conf file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put the port between double quotes:

```
gen.db.port="27017"
```

Comment: I have already tried that and it was throwing Configuration error: Configuration error[application.conf: 46: port has type STRING rather than OBJECT]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a colon

`gen.dn.port:"26017"`

Here's a link to the current documentation

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/Configuration

Answer (score 0):

You are propably using wrong method to extract the data from config. I assume you use it like:

```
current.configuration.getConfig("gen.db.port")
```

But this method returns play.api.Configuration and expects an object to be under the path "gen.db.port" (as it is mentioned in the error). Since under the "gen.db.port" path you have a number, you should change the method to:

```
current.configuration.getNumber("gen.db.port")
```